# PHP Explode and Get_Url: Not Showing up the URL

Tags: php, explode, geturl

its a little bit hard to understand.

in the header.php i have this code:

```
<?
$ID = $link;
$url = downloadLink($ID);
?>
```

I get the ID with this Variable $link --> 12345678
and with $url i get the full link from the functions.php

in the functions.php i have this snippet

```
function downloadlink ($d_id)
  {
    $res = @get_url ('' . 'http://www.example.com/' . $d_id . '/go.html');
    $re = explode ('<iframe', $res);
    $re = explode ('src="', $re[1]);
    $re = explode ('"', $re[1]);
    $url = $re[0];
    return $url;
  }
```

and normally it prints the url out.. but, i cant understand the code..

Comment: where does get_url() comes from?

Comment: This code is a mess, no one will touch this with a 6-foot pole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's written in kind of a strange way, but basically what `downloadLink()` does is this:

1. Download the HTML from `http://www.example.com/<ID>/go.html`
2. Take the HTML, and split it at every point where the string `<iframe` occurs.
3. Now take everything that came after the **first** `<iframe` in the HTML, and split it at every point where the string `src="` appears.
4. Now take everything after the first `src="` and split it at every point where `"` appears.
5. Return whatever was **before** the first `"`.

So it's a pretty poor way of doing it, but effectively it looks for the first occurence of this in the HTML code:

```
<iframe src="<something>"
```

And returns the `<something>`.

*Edit: a different method, as requested in comment*:

There's not really any particular "right" way to do it, but a fairly straightforward way would be to change it to this:

```
function downloadlink ($d_id)
{
    $html = @get_url ('' . 'http://www.example.com/' . $d_id . '/go.html');
    preg_match('/\<iframe src="(.+?)"/', $html, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, normally it takes the url in the iframe.. how can i get it the right way?

Comment: how can i print the url? with:
<?
$ID = $link;
$url = downloadLink($ID);
?>
<?php echo $url; ?> ?

Comment: :( nothing happens or should I write <?php echo $matches;?> ?