# PHP Explode: How to Download and Split a Specific HTML Part?

Tags: php, explode

example: at this domain http://www.example.com/234234/go.html is only one iframe-code

how can i get the url in the iframe-code?

go.html:

```
<iframe style="width: 99%;height:80%;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid grey;" src="i want this url" scrolling="auto" id="iframe_content"></iframe>
```

i have this snippet, but its very bad coded..

```
function downloadlink ($d_id)
  {
    $res = @get_url ('' . 'http://www.example.com/' . $d_id . '/go.html');
    $re = explode ('<iframe', $res);
    $re = explode ('src="', $re[1]);
    $re = explode ('"', $re[1]);
    $url = $re[0];
    return $url;
  }
```

thank you!

Comment: I added a different method to my answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563256/php-explode-and-get-url-not-showing-up-the-url/2563295#2563295

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a html parser such as [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse html.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');

// Find all iframes
foreach($html->find('iframe') as $element)
   echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Comment: Wow! The same snippet, 15 seconds apart. :)

Comment: thank you, but the simple_html_dom.php has 36KB! :) that's big for this little function, or is there another smaller file to use?

Comment: php can parse a 36kb file faster than it takes to read from the disk ;) Trust me the programmer speed is way more important than code speed in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what scope you have here - is it just that snippet, or are you browsing whole pages?

If you're browsing whole pages, you could use the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).
A slightly modified example from their site:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all iframes
foreach($html->find('iframe') as $element)
       echo $element->style . '<br>';
```

This sample code goes through all `iframes` on the page, and outputs their `src` property.

PHP has built-in functions for this as well (like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)), but I find the DOM Parser very nice and easy to handle (as you can see).

Comment: Yeah, but thats because I took the time to actually insert a link to the needed library :D